# PHP Database Search and retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

Okay. I have been searching Google and have not found exactly what I am looking for. 
I have a form and a database. Once form is submitted the info is entered into a database.

Now I have a page I want for people to search. They will search by the name (Name Only). Which was entered into database. Once name is entered on search form....It will query database and spit out results from tables I choose.from that name...(So lets say that one name there is 10 tables but I only want to retrieve 5 of them for the individual....
Is this making sense?

I just need someone to direct me to right place so I can see how to do it. I am stumped.

Thanks for the help..

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. What you want to do is deciding at runtime which tables to search, depending from the name you have received in INPUT?

Comment: Well you described it perfectly yourself what you need to do. If you got as far as doing the form and `insert` into the DB, surely you can write some code to `select` based on someone's keyword entered in a form? Then ask coding specific questions for your code if it doesn't work etc.

Comment: When they filled out form for they entered a name. So they will search by name..Once name is entered they will click submit and it will query info from that database for that name only. Results will come up...with info i choose.

Comment: yes yes, that sounds like it! :) so what code do you have so far?

Comment: Wait... what do you mean when you say tables? Are you actually referring to what are commonly known as such? (see solution below) Or are you referring to records? PS Do you really think he's described himself perfectly, @james ? That's not so clear to me. ;-)

Comment: It could certainly be a bit clearer, and we need to see some code

Answer (score -1):

If the strategy for picking up the table where to make the lookup is known in advance, you could do something like?

```
$tableFor['a'] = 'customers_1';
$tableFor['b'] = 'customers_2';
$tableFor['c'] = 'customers_2';
[...]
$tableFor['y'] = 'customers_19';
$tableFor['z'] = 'customers_20';
```

Then, when you get the name (say from $_GET['name']), you can do something like:

```
// Index is first letter of name
$table = $tableFor[lcfirst(substr($_GET['name'],0,1))];
query("SELECT * FROM ". $table);
```

This is of course very rough. But I hope it conveys the idea.

Comment: This is code. But how do I use and integrate the search. `<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where cars.carType = 'chevy' AND cars.active = 1") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$row['name'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Price:</th> <td>".$row['Price'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?> `

Comment: you need to edit your question and add the code, and do so for your other 2 questions for this same script too. You need to be clear with what you're asking or people cannot help :)

Comment: lol. I tried posting code and it crunches together. Or it wont let me post because it says to many characters.

Comment: Bro. I didn't down-vote you. would never do that with someone trying to help. My post was even downvoted. I have posted on here before but code is not working when I add it..Im frustrated..I want a form to search database and spit out results from it.

Comment: "spit out results from tables I choose.from" ...where is this taking place in the snipped you posted? What you are trying to do is very basic. My best suggestion is to spend some time on most basic books/docs before visiting SO.

Comment: No worries. Wasn't referring to you above, @X_JuDaH_X ;-)